# SQL Query how to add non existing column

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello guys i need help im stuck dont bully me for this i know it can be easy for you but im just bad at thinking lol :D read few times the manual on w3school and etc but still dont understand this nonsense

i need and sql query which can count how many real estate objects agent has , the database that im currently working on sql is about real estate its in lithuanian , the task is to list agent name(AgVardas), surname(AgPavardė) , phone (AgTelefonas), agency name(AgentūrosPavadinimas), and real estate objects(Nekilnojamuobektuskaicius) that agent has. The names in () these brackets are original values in my native language (Lithuanian)
i have to use the query with inner join
because its in other tables

the databases 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cwuf.jpg

the code query  i have tried is

```
SELECT `AgPavardė`,`AgVardas`,`AgTelefonas`,`AgentūrosPavadinimas`
FROM `agentai`
    INNER JOIN agentūros ON agentūros.AgentūrosNr = agentai.AgentūrosNr
```

it works and all but i need to add another column to show me Real estate objects that agent owns(number)

example how it should look

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve4Pd.jpg

So the question is how to do so?

Comment: in which table Real estate objects are?
Would you mind converting all your Lithuvanian words to English please.
Also please avoid the images and tag your database server

Comment: the table Real estate objects are in none of them i have to add this column in to my query

Comment: Please, don't post questions with half a text in non-English in future. It confuses a lot. Instead give a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So, real estate objects are in??? in ads table?

Comment: they're in none of them u just have to add it the VarunTiwari got it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the column and table names in the below query with your Lithuanian names and it should work.

```
SELECT agent.Agent_Name, agent.Agent_Surname, agent.Agent_Phone , agency.Agency_name, COUNT(ad.ad_number) as Real_Estate_Objects
FROM tbl_agent agent
INNER JOIN tbl_agency agency ON agency.agency_number = agent.agency_number
INNER JOIN tbl_ads ad ON ad.agent_number = agent.agent_number
GROUP BY agent.Agent_Name, agent.Agent_Surname, agent.Agent_Phone , agency.Agency_name
```

Comment: I think by real_estate_objects he meant how many ads a agent has against his/her name. Its not in the database as it is just the count of ads for a particular agent.

Comment: @Froster - I think there would be one ad for one real estate object with all other attributes like property type, number of rooms, location, agent . So if we count the number of ads for each agent the we have the number of real estate objects ( properties) for that agent.

Comment: yea man u got it right i meant how many real estate objects agents has in ads database its not in database i just have to make a column that i have shared in example photo a number of objects that all agents owns/have

Comment: @Froster - I am glad that it helps. You can change the names with your Lithuanian names. If it solves your question then please accept my answer and upvote it. Thanks

Comment: thx m8 it solved my problem you're the one who got it right thank you so much

Comment: @Froster - esate laukiami :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to select `AgentId` and count of the agent's real estate objects first. You do so like this.

```
SELECT AgentūrosNr, COUNT(Nekilnojamuobektuskaicius) as AgentObjectsCount 
FROM agentūros 
GROUP BY AgentūrosNr
```

Then join the result with agent's info and select info columns + count column

```
SELECT `AgPavardė`,`AgVardas`,`AgTelefonas`,`AgentūrosPavadinimas`, AgentObjectsCount 
FROM `agentai`
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT AgentūrosNr, COUNT(Nekilnojamuobektuskaicius) as AgentObjectsCount 
  FROM agentūros 
  GROUP BY AgentūrosNr
) agentsWithCount
ON agentsWithCount.AgentūrosNr = agentai.AgentūrosNr
```

Comment: i get this error #1054 - Unknown column 'Nekilnojamuobektuskaicius' in 'field list'

Comment: as i said the column 'Nekilnojamuobektuskaicius' is not in one of these databases

Comment: You have a column named Nekilnojamuobektuskaicius? I pity the poor soul who has to administer to this after you're gone

Comment: @Froster change `Nekilnojamuobektuskaicius` to whatever your column of real estate objects is.